# why cant i check if my email and mob no already exist or not?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php file in which I am trying to check if the email already exists or not.

```
        <?php
include_once("connection.php");

$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];
$mobno=$_REQUEST['mobno'];


  $checkemail="SELECT * FROM dhruv_users WHERE email= '$_REQUEST[email]'";

  $checkmob="SELECT * FROM dhruv_users WHERE mobno= '$_REQUEST[mobno]'";


$rsemail = mysqli_query($conn,$checkemail);
$rsmob = mysqli_query($conn,$checkno);

$dataemail = mysqli_num_rows($rsemail);
$datamob = mysqli_num_rows($rsmob);


    if($dataemail >= 1) {
     echo "exists";
}

    else if($datamob >= 1)

    {
        echo "exists";
        }


else{

    $select=mysqli_query($conn,"select max(id) as id from dhruv_users");

       if($data=mysqli_fetch_array($select))
       {
        $id=$data['id'];
        $id++;
      }

    else
    {
    $id=1;
    }


    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into dhruv_users VALUES ('$id','$name','$email','$mobno','$pass')");
    if($query)
    {
    echo "success";


    }

    else{
    echo "unsuces";
    }
```

}

```
 ?>
```

There is no error but data gets entered successfuly without checking mob no if it exists or not.

Entering same mob no again and again shows success message instead of exist message.

Comment: Please check answer below

Comment: @RameshKumar You don't need to comment when you post an answer, the questioner is notified automatically.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much...i will keep in mind. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you use mysqli_num_rows instead of mysqli_fetch_array with MYSQLI_NUM  .

Try the following

```
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,$check);
$dataa = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
if($dataa > 1) {
    echo "User Already in Exists<br/>";
}
```

Comment: mysqli_num_rows returns the count of rows in the result set.

Comment: dear Roshni Hegde..pls help me again here, I editted the question.

Comment: change `$rsmob = mysqli_query($conn,$checkno);`  to  `$rsmob = mysqli_query($conn,$checkmob);`  There is no variable with `$checkno` . For checking mobile number you have used variable  `$checkmob`.

Comment: Thanku for ur help mam!

Answer (score -1):

You need to count the result which you getting from DB.

There is a logical error in code. Please have a look on code below:-

**Your code**

```
if($dataa[0] > 1) {
    echo "User Already in Exists<br/>";
}
```

**Replace above with:**

```
if(count($dataa) > 1) {
    echo "User Already in Exists<br/>";
}
```

Comment: `$dataa` is one row of results, not an array of all the results, or `null` if nothing is found. Don't use `count`, just test if it's not null. `if ($dataa)`.

Comment: @DHRUVTHAKKAR I don't know why you use two query...use single query for that

Comment: how to? pls explain

Comment: @DHRUVTHAKKAR  $rsmob = mysqli_query($conn,$checkno); change the variable name

Comment: "SELECT * FROM dhruv_users WHERE email= '$_REQUEST[email]' and  mobno= '$_REQUEST[mobno]'"

Answer (score -2):

You need to write your query with proper quotes. It's unable to recognize the email index of $_REQUEST. Also, use mysqli_num_rows function.

Refer to the code below for best possible practice:

```
$check   =    "SELECT * FROM dhruv_user WHERE email= '" . $_REQUEST['email'] . "'";
$rs      =    mysqli_query($conn,$check);

if ($rs) {
    $rowcount    =    mysqli_num_rows($rs);
    if ($rowcount) {
        echo "User already exists<br/>";
    }  
}
```

Comment: You don't know that PHP replaces variables inside double quotes?